# Display only certain parameters in top

Tags: top

I have a question pertaining the 'top' command and dissecting it. What I mean by that is say for instance I wanted to display only particular parameters while top is running live, I want to only display the following parameters:

The current time, CPU utilization, current memory utilization, current disk space utilization, and currently logged in users, what would I do to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Different systems have different top implementations, but in general it isn't very configurable. It's meant to show information about memory and CPU usage; disk space and logged-in users are not its job. Conversely, *not* showing lists of processes isn't its job either.

If you want a configurable system monitor, try [conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net/). It's GUI-based. Or [nagios](https://www.nagios.org/)'s web-based dashboards.

If you want to display information of your choice in a terminal, you can use the [`watch` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watch_(Unix)) to run a program every few seconds. Pass it a shell script that displays the information you want. For example:

```
watch ./my-favorite-statistics
```

with `my-favorite-statistics` containing something like

```
#!/bin/sh
vmstat
df
who
```

For the CPU and memory part, you may want something nicer than `vmstat`. Linux's `free` might help for memory, or you can massage the output of `vmstat`.

Comment: This is excellent Gilles, you have put me towards the correct direction. I will definitely try some of the mentioned ideas. Thanks a ton!